# "Sparkling up" - Phrasal Verb or not

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I am confused about the use of "up" after sparkling in below sentence. Is "Sparkling up" a phrasal Verb? What is the difference in meaning  if we don't use "up".

"***Our home was sparkling up with lights and joys and happiness that this festival brings with it***."

I searched but didn't find that "sparkling up" is a Phrasal Verb.

Comment: I don't think it is regularly used, but the idea is similar to "lighted up" or "lit up", except that the visible light is sparkling.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know **sparkling up** is not a phrasal verb although it looks like one.

If you leave out **up**the sentence sounds a little more natural and flowing.

In the sentence below sparkling refers to how bright, shining and glittering the lights are in the house.

Our home was **sparklin**g  with lights and joys and happiness that this festival brings with it."

Sparkling is an adjective that is also often used to describe the stars in the night sky.